# How to create two seperated DSL connections and use them for different subnets

Tags: voip, pppoe, dsl

First excuse my bad english please.

My Problem is, that, with my internet provider(Alice DSL) i have two PPPOE connections, one for "ordinary internet" and one for Voip. My Question is how can i create two connections and tell ubuntu to send voip data via the first connection and use the second connection for "ordinary internet"?
I do not want to bundle them, and i do not want to make failover

I would be glad if someone has a solution to my Problem

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for something called Split Access (correct) or Split Routing (layman's term).

Have a read through the (4.2.1. Split access)http://www.lartc.org/lartc.html#AEN267 section of the Linux Advanced Routing & Traffic Control HOWTO to see if that's what you need.

You still configure both PPPoE connections, but one of them gets marked as the default interface for all traffic and then you use `ip route` and `ip rule` commands to add specific routes for your VoIP servers via the other connection. Note that you need to know the IP addresses of all your VoIP servers - you can't use `ip` to move traffic based on port numbers.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply Phooey! I have not read the Text recommended by you, because i didn't even know what i was searching (i always found infos about failover and loadbalancing, but never for my specific problem) for :). Now i hope i know what do search for.